# checking the objecttype in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA we are using the API

> Repository.GetContextObject()

to get the current selected objects in EA.But how to check whether the selected object is of type Element or package or diagram in EA using API

> Repository.GetContextItemType()

Answer (score 1):

Test for `Element.ObjectType`

- 4 = Element
- 5 = Package
- 8 = Diagram

Read the documentation for the whole list.